# SQlite NUMERIC data types size

Tags: database, types, sqlite, precision

I've been testing out sqlite3 types for efficiency on a mobile app but I'm getting strange behavior.

I created a table this way:

```
create table numeric_t(int_4 INTEGER(4), int_8 INTEGER(8), real_4 REAL(4), real_8 REAL(8), new_real DOUBLE, int_1 INTEGER(1));
```

And am setting values and seing which rows show how many decimals and so on...

Was I wrong to assume that:
- the INTEGER columns should not be able to store numbers with decimals?
- the INTEGER(1), INTEGER(4) and REAL(4) should not be able to store as many decimal places as the others?

Thanks

[Check out this snapshot of my results.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30415492/sqlite_snap.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQLite, column types do not restrict data types:

```
> CREATE TABLE t(i INTEGER);
> INSERT INTO T VALUES(1);
> INSERT INTO T VALUES(1.23);
> INSERT INTO T VALUES('forty-two');
> SELECT typeof(i) FROM t;
integer
real
text
```

To quote the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.
>   [...]
>   Any column ... may be used to store a value of any storage class.

Comment: So when creating an sqlite table, INTEGER(1) or INTEGER(10) will have the same memory footprint and performance when written to/read from?

Comment: Alright thanks alot, I'l post another question off of this one for more (:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284965/sqlite-make-sure-input-data-is-correct-length