# Sqlite make sure input data is correct length

Tags: database, types, sqlite, precision

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279595/sqlite-numeric-data-types-size) to which I got a great answer but which bring many other questions.

Say I've created a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE test(my_id INTEGER(2));
```

How can I make sure that when INSERTING data in there (or imporing from csv atually) the field is exactly an INTEGER(2), not INTEGER(1) or anything else it would dynamically stretch to..?
If I cannot are there no memory/performance issues with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values imported from CSV files are strings (but [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) might change that).

To ensure that values are in a certain range, add an explicit constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    my_id INTEGER CHECK (my_id BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
);
```

Regardless of how they're declated, integer values are stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending only on the magnitude of the value.

Comment: Is there a way to check that all the imported csv values are really strings? Because it doesn't seem to be that way, I can do numeric operations on them and they are accurate...

Comment: Most numeric operations automatically convert to numbers. To check types, use the [typeof](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof) function.